Find the index S such that the leaders of the sequences A[0], A[1], ..., A[S] and A[S + 1], A[S + 2], ..., A[N - 1] are the same
I was trying to solve the above mentioned problem , the description is as follows :
A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.
The leader of this array is the value that occurs in more than half of the elements of A.
An equi leader is an index S such that 0 ≤ S < N − 1 and two sequences A[0], A[1], ..., A[S] and A[S + 1], A[S + 2], ..., A[N − 1] have leaders of the same value.
For example, given array A such that:
A[0] = 4
A[1] = 3
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 4
A[5] = 2

we can find two equi leaders:
0, because sequences: (4) and (3, 4, 4, 4, 2) have the same leader, whose value is 4.
2, because sequences: (4, 3, 4) and (4, 4, 2) have the same leader, whose value is 4.
The goal is to count the number of equi leaders.
Write a function:
func Solution(A []int) int
that, given a non-empty array A consisting of N integers, returns the number of equi leaders.
For example, given:
A[0] = 4
A[1] = 3
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 4
A[5] = 2

the function should return 2, as explained above.
Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000,000..1,000,000,000].
I was able to solve it ,but my code fails the performance tests with timeout error .My code is as follows :
func Solution(A []int) int {

    equiLeaderCount := 0
    var equiLdrLft, equiLdrRght int

    for i := 0; i < len(A)-1; i++ {

        lhs := A[:(i + 1)]
        rhs := A[(i + 1):]

        lshLen := len(lhs)
        rshLen := len(rhs)
    
        lshMap := make(map[int]int)
        rshMap := make(map[int]int)

        //for left
        //for just single elem
        if lshLen == 1 {
            equiLdrLft = lhs[0]

        }
        for _, val := range lhs {
            lshMap[val]++
        }

        for k, val2 := range lshMap {
            if val2 > (lshLen / 2) {
                equiLdrLft = k
            }
        }
        //for right
        if rshLen == 1 {
            equiLdrRght = rhs[0]

        }
        for _, val := range rhs {
            rshMap[val]++
        }

        for k2, val3 := range rshMap {
            if val3 > rshLen/2 {
                equiLdrRght = k2
            }
        }

        // comparison
        if equiLdrLft == equiLdrRght {
        
            equiLeaderCount++
            equiLdrLft, equiLdrRght = 0, 0

        }

    }
    return equiLeaderCount
}

Let me know of better solution with comparatively lesser time complexity
